# Conditional joins on the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a messaging app and trying to reduce the amount of queries but running into some trouble trying to get the context for message replies. Currently, when a message is a reply, I'm saving the ID of the message it's replying to a column called `replying`, and fetching it as an additional query after the fact.

For example, this is my current query.

```
SELECT id, message, time, user, replying 
FROM messages 
WHERE conversation = ? 
ORDER BY ai DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

Ideally I'd like it to also `SELECT id, message, time, user WHERE id = previous.replying` when applicable.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input tables and expected output?

Comment: Just select the parent message in the initial select `SELECT m.id, m.message, m.time, m.user, m.replying,  p.message parent_message, p.time parent_time, p.user parent_user FROM messages m left join messages p on p.id=m.replying WHERE`